# How do i figure out the x and y position of my mouse in d3?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am using JS, D3, mouse events and HTML.

I'm trying to figure out the x and y position of my mouse when hovering over an SVG.

my code

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", function(){
        let x = d3.select(this).attr("x")
        console.log(x)
    })
```

I have looked online and found people speaking about using `d3.mouse(this)` however i keep getting d3.mouse() is not a function.

Can someone please help me :)
thanks

Comment: What version of D3 are you using? `d3.mouse` became `d3.pointer` in the latest version.

Comment: Thankyou :) put it as an answer and i will mark answered :)

Answer (score 9):

In D3 v6, [`d3.mouse` became `d3.pointer`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#cell-2):

```
let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("mouseover", e => console.log(d3.pointer(e)) )
```

Comment: I'm getting [undefined, undefined]

Comment: The answer is .on("mouseover", (e) => { console.log(d3.pointer(e) ) })